# $\cos28 + \sin28= k^3\cos17=$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos28^\circ +\sin28^\circ = k^3$

then $\cos17^\circ = $?. Find in terms of $k$.

MY ATTEMPT:
I tried finding $\cos28^\circ - \sin28^\circ$ in terms of $k$. Then I found out $\cos28^\circ$ with the help of the two equations. Finally I found out $\cos17^\circ$ from $\cos28^\circ$. However the answer is coming in terms of $\sqrt{k^6 - 2}$, which is way too complicated. The answer simply given here is $\frac{k^3}{\sqrt2}$.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\cos A+\sin A=\sqrt2\cos(45^\circ-A)$$

Here $A=?$

Comment: Taking A= 28` we get the answer. WOW! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Find $$\cos(45^\circ-17^\circ)$$  and $$\sin(45^\circ-17^\circ)$$

and use $\cos45^\circ=\sin45^\circ=\text{?}$